Reload Page if front-end has an update (Vue 3)
I am developing a Vue 3 application and am experiencing an issue with user experience during deployments. Upon deployment, users are required to manually delete their cache or press Ctrl + Shift + R to refresh the page. This is inconvenient because they are unaware of the deployment status.
My objective is to implement a  function that detects changes in the front end and triggers a notification to users, prompting them to update their browsers.
To achieve this, I have considered using a service worker. However, I am uncertain if this approach is the most suitable solution. I have referenced a tutorial for Vue 2 (https://dev.to/drbragg/handling-service-worker-updates-in-your-vue-pwa-1pip) for guidance, but I would appreciate feedback on whether this approach aligns with my requirements or if there is another solution. The alert must appear if there is a single h1 update.
I will share the code I have implemented in case it is on the correct path.
registrer-service-worker.js
import { register } from "register-service-worker";
//import { useSWStore } from "src/stores/sw-store.js";

//const swStore = useSWStore();
// The ready(), registered(), cached(), updatefound() and updated()
// events passes a ServiceWorkerRegistration instance in their arguments.
// ServiceWorkerRegistration: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration

register(process.env.SERVICE_WORKER_FILE, {


  // The registrationOptions object will be passed as the second argument
  // to ServiceWorkerContainer.register()
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register#Parameter

  // registrationOptions: { scope: './' },

  ready(registration) {
    console.log('Service worker is active.', registration);
  },

  registered(registration) {
    console.log('Service worker has been registered.', registration);
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(registration.update());
      registration.update();
    }, 5000);
  },

  cached(/* registration */) {
    console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.');
  },

  updatefound(registration) {
    console.log('New content is downloading.', registration);
  },

  updated(registration) {
    console.log('New content is available; please refresh.', registration);
    // document.dispatchEvent(
    //   new CustomEvent('swUpdated', { detail: registration })
    // );

    // self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    //   if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    //     self.skipWaiting();
    //   }
    // });
    
    // self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    //   event.waitUntil(
    //     self.clients.claim().then(() => {
    //       self.clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then(clients => {
    //         clients.forEach(client => {
    //           client.postMessage({ type: 'swUpdated' });
    //         });
    //       });
    //     })
    //   );
    // });
    //swStore.setNewVersionAvailable();
  },

  offline() {
    console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
  },

  error(err) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', err);
  },
});

App.vue
<template>
  <router-view />
  <div id="app">
    <ServiceWorkerUpdate />
    <!-- <h1>Vue 3 app</h1> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import ServiceWorkerUpdate from 'src/components/ServiceWorkerUpdate.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    ServiceWorkerUpdate
  },
  name: "App"
});
</script>

Service Worker Update (not finished)
<template>
    <div v-if="updateAvailable" class="update-notification">
      <p>Update aviable! Please reload.</p>
      <button @click="reloadApp">Reload</button>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
  
  export default {
    setup() {
      const updateAvailable = ref(false);
  
      const reloadApp = () => {
        if (updateAvailable.value) {
          if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then(registration => {
              if (registration){
                window.location.reload(true);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      };
  
      onMounted(() => {
        document.addEventListener('swUpdated', () => {
          updateAvailable.value = true;
        });
      });
  
      return {
        updateAvailable,
        reloadApp
      };
    },
  };
  </script>

All that remains is to thank you for your help.

is your app a PWA or SPA?  If you're adding a service worker just to detect changes to your SPA, I would not.  What you want to do is called "cache busting".  Research it and you'll find many different strategies.  For a Vue 3 app with Vite, you might want to try this answer

If you want users using your site to be aware the instant a new version is deployed and notify them of such, then a service worker is correct.

The app is actually PWA
